# TMainMenu SubItems Alignment

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I just noticed that with DelphiXE4 on Windows 8.1 all of my MainMenu submenu items are right aligned even with newly created projects. What controls submenu alignment and how can I fix this?
I created a new vcl project, added a TMainMenu component, added submenu items, compile and run the project and this is what I get.

[image]

This is a screenshot of the menu in the IDE
[image]

Comment: Yes... that was the problem... It must have been caused during windows 8 to 8.1 update.